# shopping cart to my application on facebook

Tags: java, facebook, reference, shopping-cart

I am using `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` and make an application.

Eventually, I want that my application will be available on Facebook.

I want to enable my users to buy products. what is the securest site that give me this feature? I read about `Ecwid` but I will be happy to know more suggestions. I know that I can do it with `Paypal` but the fees of any transaction is too big.

any help appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application will be on facebook`s platform you`d better use facebook credit: You can start [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/)